# Bold selected Text dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, tags

I want Bold a part of my string dynamically . when my user select part a text in ASP.Net and click Bold button than his text going to Bold . 
what am i going to do ?
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: can you post any code? what is the control being used for the text?

Comment: Sorry . i dont understand your question

Comment: This is a javascript/jQuery Question. Perhaps this is a start: http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html and this http://api.jquery.com/select/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of id_123 in someFunc use the id of the DOM object that you want the onclick registered with.

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id="id_123" onClick="someFunc()">Here is some bolded text </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function someFunc() {
        var value = document.getElementById('id_123');    
        value.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight: bold;');
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He wants only the selected text in a Textbox to be bold after users clicked `bold` Button and not all Text.

Comment: it doesn't say anything about a Textbox anywhere.. could just as easily be an asp:Label or straight up html element.  My answer holds.

Answer (score 0):

On button click add style to the text.

are you using javascript , or js libraries like jquery.

```
style=" font-weight:bold"
```

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/17/10144717/css-style-change-when-im-clicking-link-button.aspx